# Update the project name in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

How can I update the project name in Eclipse?

I have changed the project name by using "refactor" and "rename", but when I install the .apk in my device, it still shows the old project name.

How can I fix it and what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Project name got nothing to application name. And there's no really anything like one application name on Android, but the label of Activity (one or more) user can access from his launcher. This is declared in AndroidManifest with `android:label` for every `Activity` with proper `intent-filter`.

```
    <activity
        android:name=".StartActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

[See docs.](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#label)

Comment: thanks for your help! also I have found that it need to change the project name in                                                  res -> values -> strings.xml -> app_name -> (change the name)

Comment: Yes, because it was referenced (`@string/app_name`) in Manifest. If this answers your question, please accept the answer: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235